# Is there a way in CSS to hide the up and down buttons in a Spark Scroller or Spark Datagrid?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

Is there a way in CSS to hide the up and down buttons in a Spark Scroller or Spark Datagrid?

Comment: Same answer as your other question: only with a custom skin. You just have to take a look at the default skin to assess for yourself whether something like this can be done through CSS or not.

Comment: You can create a custom skin class and then assign that skin class to all scrollers using the skinClass style.

Comment: Thanks guys. I was hoping there was some secret way I didn't know of such as the old programaticSkin method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. It requires a custom skin.